# Cannot verify erc20 contract on etherscan because cannot find ABI for mist wallet

Tags: ether

Where do I find the contract ABI to verify in etherscan. Contract launch from mist wallet 0.9.3

Answer (score 1):

So, in Mist under "Contracts" you select the contract you monitor/deployed, among right-hand-side icons click "Show Interface":
[image]
[image]

It will show you ABI, which should be similar (for the same contract) to the one you can find on Etherscan under "Contract Source" tab in the middle of the page:
[image]